# How to add the image file from the form to the jQuery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working a jQuery file upload helper and I need to understand how can I append the File from the form or the Form data as a whole to the request.

I have worked with the ASP.NET code to accept image from the Request and handle the further code, but when I try to use it using jQuery `$.ajax()` I can't get it to work.

I have been though Stack Overflow questions, and I have tried using `FormData` appending the data from the `input[type="file"]` (input for the file element). But each time (on the server) the block that is executed that tells me there is no file with the request.

Here is the ASP.NET code (UploadFile page)

```
@{
    var fileName = "Not running!";
    if(IsPost) {
        if(Request.Files.Count > 0) {
            var image = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();   
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName) + " From server";
        } else {
            fileName = "No file attached! From Server";
        }
    }
    Response.Write(fileName);
}
```

The jQuery code is as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/UploadFile',
            data: new FormData().append('file',
                  document.getElementById("image").files[0]),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#result').html('Image uploaded was: ' + data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am already scratching my head since I can't get the file content on the serverside.

How can I send the file to the server, or the entire form data to the server, anything would be welcome!

Comment: you can not get the value of the file input and send it via AJAX, need to use iframe in order to do that

Comment: @AminJafari, I have had a look at some other plugins, that allow this feature.

Comment: and they all use iframe

Answer (score 0):

Try using handler for this and Newtonsoft.json.dll for these purpose.
For jQuery

```
(document).ready(function () {
$('form input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'handler.ashx', // put a handler instead of direct path
        data: new FormData().append('file',
              document.getElementById("image").files[0]),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#result').html('Image uploaded was: ' + data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

In asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile up = context.Request.Files[0];
    System.IO.FileInfo upinfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(up.FileName);

        System.Drawing.Image upimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(up.InputStream);
        string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/temp"); // this is the server path   where you'll be saving your image
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        string fileName;
        fileName = up.FileName;
        string newFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        System.IO.FileInfo fInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
        newFilename = string.Format("{0}{1}", newFilename, fInfo.Extension);
        string strFileName = newFilename;
        fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, newFilename);
        up.SaveAs(fileName);
        successmsg1 s = new successmsg1
        {
            status = "success",
            url = "temp/" + newFilename,
            width = upimg.Width,
            height = upimg.Height
        };

        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s));
    }
```

Comment: My ASP.NET code is working correctly, I am having a problem while working with the jQuery code, how can I pass the form data to the server?